# firebase functions update a function property from a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

[If you have another way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.]

Firebase Functions are a great way to create a simple backend. However, when there are a lot of updates, the function returns an error:

> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

This error can be resolved by setting the minInstances property, but it causes a significant change in billing as the instances stay up all the time.

So, I created a script to count the number of active instances at the same time in the last three weeks, and I want to use this to update the function hourly with the calculated value.

This is the code:

```
    const functionName = 'FUNCTION-NAME';

    const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
        scopes: [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.read',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
        ]
    });

    const monitoring = google.monitoring({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: auth
    });

    const getInstancesCount = (async (functionName, startTime, endTime) => {

        const options = {
            name: `projects/${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}`,
            filter: `metric.type="cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/function/instance_count" AND resource.label.function_name="${functionName}"`,
            "interval.startTime": startTime.toISOString(),
            "interval.endTime": endTime.toISOString(),
            "aggregation.alignmentPeriod.seconds": 3600,
            "aggregation.perSeriesAligner": 'ALIGN_MEAN'
        };
    
        const response = await monitoring.projects.timeSeries.list(options);
        const timeSeries = response.data.timeSeries;
        const averageActiveInstances = timeSeries.length > 0 ? timeSeries[0].points[0].value.doubleValue : 0;

        console.log(`Average active instances for function ${functionName} between ${startTime.toISOString()} and ${endTime.toISOString()}: ${averageActiveInstances}`);

        return averageActiveInstances;

    });

    const weeks = 3;
    let totalActiveInstances = 0;

    for (let week = 1; week <= weeks; week++) {
        const startTime = new Date();
        const endTime = new Date();
        endTime.setHours(endTime.getHours() + 1);

        totalActiveInstances = await getInstancesCount(functionName, startTime, endTime);
    }

    const averageActiveInstances = totalActiveInstances / weeks;
    

    console.log(`Average active instances for function ${functionName} : ${averageActiveInstances}`);
```

It works perfectly, but now I need to update the function to use the calculated minInstances value. To do this, I created the following code:

```
    const locationId = 'us-central1';
    const projectId = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;    

    const weeks = 3;
    let totalActiveInstances = 0;

    for (let week = 1; week <= weeks; week++) {
        const startTime = new Date();
        const endTime = new Date();
        endTime.setHours(endTime.getHours() + 1);

        totalActiveInstances = await getInstancesCount(functionName, startTime, endTime);
    }

    const averageActiveInstances = totalActiveInstances / weeks;
    

    console.log(`Average active instances for function ${functionName} : ${averageActiveInstances}`);

    const cloudfunctions = google.cloudfunctions({
        version: 'v1',
        auth: auth
      });

    // obter a configuração atual da função
    const { data } = await cloudfunctions.projects.locations.functions.get({
        name: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${locationId}/functions/${functionName}`
    });

    // atualizar a propriedade minInstances
    data.minInstances = Math.floor(averageActiveInstances); // novo valor para minInstances

    // atualizar a configuração da função
    await cloudfunctions.projects.locations.functions.patch({
        name: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${locationId}/functions/${functionName}`,
        requestBody: data
    });
```

However, I'm receiving the following error, and the function is not updated:

> Failed to verify the provided Cloud Storage Signed URL.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

**Answer:**

The problem is the permission on service account used from firebase. I needed to set permission to read and write to storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An authentication problem in the script used to update the Firebase Function configuration may be the cause of the error `"Failed to verify the provided Cloud Storage Signed URL."`

The problem could be caused by the service account rights, the process of authentication, or the API answer.
The service account permissions should be checked, new authentication credentials should be created, and the script should have error handling code added.

More details on this can be found in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles) on Cloud Functions IAM roles and permissions.